# Use live feeds (RSS?) to convert USD to GBP in VB form

Tags: vb.net, vb6, rss, converters

I've searched the web and can't find the exact thing that I'm looking for - this could be because it doesn't exist, but I'll ask here anyway...

I want to use a pretty simple from written using VB, I've worked with things like RSS feeds before, but only in a HTML environment. I was wondering if there is a way to have a section of the form as a USD -> GBP converter, using a live exchange rate. Is this possible? If so, does anyone know a good source to get the live feed from? 
Any ideas, code, suggestions and criticism is welcome.
Thanks for your time.
Cal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to query the Yahoo currency converter using this function:

```
Public Function GetHTML(ByVal sURL As String) As String
'Function returns the contents of the web page at sURL
'(or the contents of the 404/error info, if sURL is 
'invalid, incorrectly formatted, etc.)
Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXmlHttp")
    xmlHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
    xmlHttp.send
    GetHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
    Set xmlHttp = Nothing
End Function
```

*Notice that it's using `ServerXmlHttp`rather than just `XmlHttp`. This is because the latter was returning an `Access denied` error when I tried it, I'm not sure why.*

Call it from your form code using something like this:

```
lblRate.caption = GetHTML("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?&f=l1&s=USDGBP=X")
```

**Note:**
AFAICT there isn't any official documentation on the Yahoo API. But there are plenty of examples of it's usage if you search online.

Comment: This is a good solution, but it has lead to another problem which I have never encountered...      Error 1 Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\x86\Debug\Alibaba.Currency.resources" Alibaba

Comment: @Cal Are you sure it's this code that's causing that error? Are you trying to write the value to a file? If not, the only thing I can think is there's maybe something (e.g. a virus-checker or firewall) that's preventing MSXML2 from writing the URL's return value in the temporary internet cache – which I think it *will* do because it's part of the Wininet library.

Comment: Wasn't your code which caused the problem... Actually I don't know what it was which caused the problem, however as it was only a small project I just re made it and copied the code over and it works perfectly, thanks a lot! I've marked your answer as correct. One issue is that sometimes the value which comes back has some strange symbols on the end, but when I get around to it I'll add a workaround with the isNumeric function I guess :P Thanks again!

Comment: @Cal I should point out that this method is really a VB6 solution. For .NET you would be better off using the `HttpWebResponse` class, which is very easy to use – see the [example given here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)